# svn diff with base of branch

Tags: svn

I feel like this is so simple, but embarrassingly I can't find information on it and I'm new to subversion.

I've created a fork with an svn copy and checked out the branch and have worked from there.  I've created a set of changesets via a series of commits on this branch from within my working copy.

I now want to see what changes I've done since the fork.  I don't want to see the changes between my changeset and the latest of the branch I've forked from - I just want to see my set of changes.  In other words, I don't care what other people have done on the branch I forked from since I forked.

What's the easiest way for me to do this?  Do I have to sift through an svn log for the base revision of my branch?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with SVN in this case.  The problem that ends up happening is that you cannot `svn diff` with base if you have committed to the repository because then that makes `BASE` the last revision you committed from your working copy.  The same thing happens when you do an `svn update`.  One way to actually log checkouts from the repository is on the server side which I know is not ideal because one would rather write some code to automatically find it for you, but as you can tell...svn has no command for that.  Your best bet is creating a server side script to keep track of that and using that from now on.